# How do I show international / transliterated names for streets in SKMaps?

Tags: ios, swift, skmaps

I have tried to play around with the internationalisation settings in SKMaps for a while, but they only seem to have an effect on the labels for cities, and not for streets.

F.ex. in Thailand, where the alphabet is completely unintelligible for foreigners, almost all street names are still displayed in the Thai alphabet. I have pasted my code dealing with the relevant settings. Any ideas what might be wrong?

```
let languageSettings = SKMapInternationalizationSettings.mapInternationalization()
languageSettings.backupToTransliterated = true
languageSettings.primaryInternationalLanguage = SKLanguage.MapLanguageEN
languageSettings.fallbackInternationalLanguage = SKLanguage.MapLanguageDE
languageSettings.primaryOption = SKMapInternationalizationOption.International
languageSettings.fallbackOption = SKMapInternationalizationOption.Transliterated
mapView.settings.mapInternationalization = languageSettings
```

**Update:**

Although these options don't work for street names, like explained in the answer below, a workaround to show street names in the latin alphabet is to use the "lite" version of the maps. This is done in the initialisation part:

```
let initSettings: SKMapsInitSettings = SKMapsInitSettings()
initSettings.mapDetailLevel = SKMapDetailLevel.Light;
SKMapsService.sharedInstance().initializeSKMapsWithAPIKey(apiKey, settings: initSettings)
```

Thanks to the SKMaps-guys for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now the transliteration option only affects city labels and POI labels but not is not yet implemented for streets.

This is one of the features we're evaluating for a future SDK update.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there anyway one could get an ETA on such a feature? Or are there eventually any hooks we could use to provide the functionality ourselves? This is bordering to a showstopper for us. I assume it would also be welcome functionality in your own apps.

Comment: For the moment we can't offer an ETA regarding this